# Laravel Mail sending email but returning false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to send a email and show any errors if needed. The following code is sending a email and I am receiving it just fine. The issue though, is that when I do the check on the $sent var, it returns false for me.

Am I just missing something here? It might be because it's late. Who knows...

```
$sent = Mail::send('emails.users.reset', compact('user', 'code'), function($m) use ($user)
{
    $m->to($user->email)->subject('Activate Your Account');
});

if( ! $sent)
{
    $errors = 'Failed to send password reset email, please try again.';
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The Mail::send() method doesn't return anything.

You can use the Mail::failures() (introduced in 4.1 I think) method to get an array of failed recipients, in your code it would look something like this.

```
Mail::send('emails.users.reset', compact('user', 'code'), function($m) use ($user)
{
    $m->to($user->email)->subject('Activate Your Account');
});

if(count(Mail::failures()) > 0){
    $errors = 'Failed to send password reset email, please try again.';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I saw all sorts of different ways while searching and I guessed I assumed what I was the correct way. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a problem with this as the if statement is after the mail::send and before the callback passed to Mail::send is executed and that's the actual part of the code which sends the email?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I missed the question somehow. I think you may be a little confused about that (been coding a lot of JS recently?) - The callback will always be executed before the if statement, it isn't called asynchronously.

Comment: Yes! isnt Mail::send() asynch? I think you could create an event that if an email wont be sent, it queues a job to resend the mail.

Comment: Mail::send() isn't async. You can queue mail by calling Mail::queue() in place of the send method as above, but that's still not technically async, it just creates a queue job instead of actually sending the mail and errors are caught by the queue worker.

Comment: Nice explanation, but I have a kind of another curiosity. Assume for example an email address is valid, but it's not sent properly because an internet disconnected. Is laravel can give a warning about it? Or maybe an emails are unsent because of something else, it's kinda an email address is not valid. Is laravel can give a warning about it too?