# Check mail is sent successfully or not on Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, smtp, laravel-5, sendmail

I have a function that can send mail on Laravel5 using this

```
/**
 *  Send Mail from Parts Specification Form
 */
 public function sendMail(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->all();

    $messageBody = $this->getMessageBody($data);

    Mail::raw($messageBody, function ($message) {
        $message->from('yourEmail@domain.com', 'Learning Laravel');
        $message->to('goper.zosa@gmail.com');
        $message->subject('Learning Laravel test email');
    });

    return redirect()->back();
 }

 /**
  * Return message body from Parts Specification Form
  * @param object $data
  * @return string
  */
 private function getMessageBody($data) {

    $messageBody = 'dummy dummy dummy dummy';
 }
```

and is sent successfully. But how to check if it was sent or not? Like

```
if (Mail::sent == 'error') {
 echo 'Mail not sent';
} else {
 echo 'Mail sent successfully.';
}
```

I'm just guessing that code.

Comment: Have you tried `Mail::failures()`

Comment: @haakym how to change my code to be able to see if that work or not? To fire that method? Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772531/laravel-mail-sending-email-but-returning-false

Comment: Yes i use that one, thanks. But how to know if that work or not?

Comment: If `failures()` doesn't return anything then it has been successfully sent.

Comment: Can I edit my code or something just to show that errors occured? If not then thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this would work but you can give it a shot

```
/**
 *  Send Mail from Parts Specification Form
 */
public function sendMail(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->all();

    $messageBody = $this->getMessageBody($data);

    Mail::raw($messageBody, function ($message) {
        $message->from('yourEmail@domain.com', 'Learning Laravel');
        $message->to('goper.zosa@gmail.com');
        $message->subject('Learning Laravel test email');
    });

    // check for failures
    if (Mail::failures()) {
        // return response showing failed emails
    }

    // otherwise everything is okay ...
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose there is an equivalent method for the number of successes? `Mail::successes()` throws an error with `Call to undefined method`.

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html nope.  Just do number of recipients minus count of failures and you will get your success count.

Comment: i got "response showing failed emails" what should i do now ?

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya Do you want to debug your failed emails? Did you check your error logs? You may also want to dive into the laravel and swiftmailer codebase to see what determines if an email is a failure.

Comment: Nice explanation, but I have a kind of another curiosity. Assume for example an email address is valid, but it's not sent properly because an internet disconnected, or something else maybe because an email address is not valid. Is laravel can give a warning about it?

Comment: Are failures limited to invalid emails? Look at my previous comment and I'm sure you'll get your answer. Here's a starting point: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L484 and https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html

Comment: how can i use when i am sending email using Notification?

Answer (score 26):

> Hope this helps

The `Mail::failures()` will return an array of failed emails.

```
Mail::send(...)

if( count(Mail::failures()) > 0 ) {

   echo "There was one or more failures. They were: <br />";

   foreach(Mail::failures() as $email_address) {
       echo " - $email_address <br />";
    }

} else {
    echo "No errors, all sent successfully!";
}
```

source : http://laravel.io/forum/08-08-2014-how-to-know-if-e-mail-was-sent

Comment: At least source the answer ;) http://laravel.io/forum/08-08-2014-how-to-know-if-e-mail-was-sent

Comment: How can i use when i am sending email from notification?

Answer (score 9):

For Laravel 9.11.0

```
Mail::failures() // is deprecated in laravel 9.11.0
```

To check if your email was sent successfully one could wrap mail send in a try catch block:

```
try {
    Mail::to($userEmail)->send($welcomeMailable);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  //Email sent failed.
}
```

or since `Mail::to($email)->send($mailable)` on success returns an instance of : `SentMessage` one could check:

```
$welcomeEmailSent = Mail::to($userEmail)->send($welcomeMailable);

if ($welcomeEmailSent instanceof \Illuminate\Mail\SentMessage) {
  //email sent success
} else {
  //email sent failed
}
```

Comment: it's not working bro. It always going to fail section in Laravel 8 Could you suggest another method?

Comment: how do you mean ?

Comment: Means to say whenever I run the below code it always print not done. I am unable to check whether the email is sent or not? could you tell me the proper method to check it. Thank you 
$response = Mail::send('emailTemplate.email', $data, function($message) use ($data) { $message->to($data['email'], 'Notification')->subject('Notification Testing email'); $message->from('example@example.com','Notification Testing email'); });
if($responseinstanceof \Illuminate\Mail\SentMessage){
  dd('done');
}else{
dd('not done');
}

Comment: wrap it in a try catch instead, if exception not caught email is sent, otherwise it failed, ```try {
    Mail::to($userEmail)->send($welcomeMailable);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  //Email sent failed.
}```

Comment: Firstly I'm very thankful to you because you're trying to solve my problem. Secondly, It's not working I did exactly what you said and I put my wrong email and it still not working.

Answer (score 4):

You may additionally can make use "Swift_TransportException" to identify any errors.

```
try{

   //code to send the mail

}catch(\Swift_TransportException $transportExp){
  //$transportExp->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Mail::failures() function for that.
It will have a collection of failed mails if it exists so you can use the code below to check for it.

```
public function sendMail(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->all();

    $messageBody = $this->getMessageBody($data);

    Mail::raw($messageBody, function ($message) use ($messageBody) {
        $message->from('yourEmail@domain.com', 'Learning Laravel');
        $message->to('goper.zosa@gmail.com');
        $message->subject($messageBody); 
    });

    // check for failed ones
    if (Mail::failures()) {
        // return failed mails
        return new Error(Mail::failures()); 
    }

    // else do redirect back to normal
    return redirect()->back();
}
```