# How to check mail is send successfully or not and save status in laravel notification?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail, laravel-notification

I'm using laravel notifications for sending email and save to database. How to check mail status after sending email and how to save it in the notification table?

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail', DbChannel::class];
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->from('test@example.com', 'Example')
        ->line('...');
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check mail is sent successfully or not on Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882357/check-mail-is-sent-successfully-or-not-on-laravel-5)

Comment: no , i ` m use laravel notifications and i want to save email status  after sending by mail channel to database...

Comment: What is your mail driver?

Comment: smtp, i use gmail for test

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: I sent the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to handle this you can define listener and event .
you first register it in App\Providers\EventServiceProvider

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\Event' => [
        'App\Listeners\EventListener',
    ],
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSendingMessage',
    ],
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSentMessage',
    ],
];
```

and then in App\Listeners\LogSendingMessage ,save send status. for example

```
   public function handle(MessageSending $event)
{
    $notification = Notification::where('id',$event->data['notification']->id)->first();
    $notification->status = "Sending";
    $notification->save();
}

public function failed(MessageSending $event, $exception)
{
    $notification = Notification::where('id',$event->data['notification']->id)->first();
    $notification->status = "Sending Event Failed";
    $notification->save();
}
```

also for LogSentMessage....
See this link for more information
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#events