# Laravel 5.4 get response from mail (AWS)

Tags: laravel-5

I am using AWS for sending mail in Laravel 5.4.  After sent the mail I need the response to track the mail status etc and all.  How will I get the response from AWS?

This I am using for send mail:

```
\Mail::to($mail_id)->send(new MailClass($email_data));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Mail sending email but returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772531/laravel-mail-sending-email-but-returning-false)

Comment: No.I need the complete response in json format  like  notificationType :"bounce",bounce{bounceType : "permanent" ,.....}